# Docusign Integration With Stripe

Tags: paypal, docusignapi

I was referred here by Docusign Customer Support - they said only devs knew the answer.  ?!?  :)

Anyway, I'm just wanting to know if it's possible to send a Docusign user to a specific website as a part of the document signing process.  E.G. I send them a user agreement to sign, and they sign it and then they get redirected to Paypal or Stripe or something to pay the fee before their signed document is complete and returned to me.

Thanks!

Comment: Docusign customer support doesn't seem to be doing their job.

Answer (score 2):

PayPal can be used in DocuSign:

[Payment Processing Feature](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-user-guide-advanced-sending-using-the-payment-processing-feature)

For more information I would contact your Account Manager for assistance on what steps/costs are required to get this enabled on your account.

Answer (score 0):

To drill down a bit, [go here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-admin-guide-add-payment-processing-information) for a any PayPal product (credit card payment) **integration into docusign**. Keep in mind that you must have sign up for one of the PayPal Products, PayPal Advanced, Payflow Link, Payflow Pro; WebSite payments pro is no longer circulating.

**Walkthrough**:

- click your profile image in the upper right and select Preferences.
  In the navigation pane on the left side of the page, under the
  Account Administration heading, click Features.
- Click the Enable Payment Processing link to go to the Payment
  Processing through PayPal Set Up page.
- Note: You must have a PayPal Payments Advanced, PayPal Payments Pro, 
  Payflow Pro or Payflow Link account to use this feature. Even if
  Enable Payment Processing is selected, the feature is not fully
  enabled until the PayPal Merchant account information is entered